# Frontend session Pimcore 5 -how to disable it?

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

Is there a way to disable session front in Pimcore 5?

I have installed new empty/blank project locally but there is a session started on front, which I wish to disable.

Any solution how to disable it ?

Screen below:

[image: Screen session]

Comment: There is no session on https://demo.pimcore.org/ - maybe there is a configuration issue in your setup?